# jquery: select input with given name and value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to check the input that is named weekday and has value = 1. I tried the line below. It checks all weekdays.

```
$('input[name = weekday], [value =1]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Do not use comma to apply both conditions on same element.

```
$('input[name=weekday][value=1]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

As a side note you should use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()` for *properties* as suggested by [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and pointed by @tyleha.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

You can use [.prop( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value) to set the checked property as shown below.

```
$('input[name=weekday][value=1]').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: You should (need?) to use `.prop` instead of `.attr` to check for such DOM properties: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

so just `.prop("checked")` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @tyleha, you are right to use prop() here. But .prop("checked") will get the value of property instead of setting. To set the property .prop("checked", true); will be used.

Answer (score 2):

No need for the comma. Try:

```
 var checked = $('input[name = weekday][value =1]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
$('input[name=weekday][value=1]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

Comma separates multiple selectors, so you were searching for inputs named "weekday" *and* elements of any type with value = 1.

To combine both criteria in one selector, just add them after one another:

```
$('input[name=weekday][value=1]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="two">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="three">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="four">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="five">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="six">

alert('1');
 $("input[value='four'][name='some\\[thing\\]']").attr("checked",true);
alert('2'); 
 $("input[value='four'][name='some\\[thing\\]']").attr("checked",false);
alert('3');
```