# jquery selector Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, selector

[image]

I am using jQuery selector to select my radio button by name and value, and i am using the code that i found on
[jquery: select input with given name and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936958/jquery-select-input-with-given-name-and-value)

But it give me an error, my name and value are match with the code:
[image]

Comment: Try `$("input[name='q_2'][value='Rerum.....']")` values within quotes..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thx it works

Comment: anytime.. Happy coding.. :)